# Remove/add MessageHandlers at runtime

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, message-handlers

How can I add or remove message handlers at runtime?
The following example does not work:

```
var logHandler = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(ApiLogHandler));

if (logHandler == null)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiLogHandler());
}
else
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Remove(logHandler);
}
```

The message handler **is added** to the list,
but it is not called in the the next requests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would inject a `MessageHandler` into the configuration at startup that is built specifically to have a dynamic list of inner message handlers, and change the interface they use from `DelegatingHandler` to a custom one, e.g.

```
public interface ICustomMessageHandler 
{
    Task SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

After this, you can create a standard `MessageHandler` that contains a list of inner handlers:

```
public class DynamicMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public List<ICustomMessageHandler> InnerHandlers { get; set; }

    public DynamicMessageHandler()
    {
        InnerHandlers = new List<ICustomMessageHandler>();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var innerHandler in InnerHandlers)
        {
            await innerHandler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This way youshould be able to modify the list of `InnerHandlers` at runtime as long as you keep a single instance of `DynamicMessageHandler` around.

Comment: Thats smart, I will give it a try :) Any idea as to why the message handler can not reconfigure at runtime?

Comment: @MathiasColpaert I suspect the configuration is "finalised" once the `GlobalConfiguration.Configure` method is called. You could try calling that method again, but it seems that would be a one time usage method.

Comment: I tried that, calling Configure again does not work :)

Comment: And if you have a message handler that implements `ICustomMessageHandler` how do you exactly await the next handler in the pipeline if you want to do things in both the request and response?
I mean you cannot do anymore `var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);` because there is no `base` anymore

Comment: If I can't it at start could I inject or add handler at runtime?